# Clarification regarding single quotes and double quotes in PHP

Tags: php

If I write something like

```
$var = 12;
echo '$var'; //$var gets printed
echo "$var"; //12 gets printed
```

But when I do something like

```
$name = 'peter'; $email = 'peter@yahoo.com';
$query = "INSERT INTO email_list (name, email)  VALUES ('$name', '$email')";
```

Why are the values of the variables getting inserted in the table?
Why do '$name' and '$email' not get inserted into the table, since they are enclosed inside single quotes?

Similarly,

```
echo 'i am going <br />';
```

is not printing: `i am going <br />`

Comment: You should just read what the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) has to say about it.

Comment: And, it is printing `i am going <br />`. You probably don't see the `<br />` because it is rendered as HTML by the browser. Change the `Content-type` header to `text/plain` or escape the angle brackets if you want `<br />` to appear on the page lexically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why the values of the variables are getting inserted in the table, why
>   not '$name' and '$email' are getting inserted in the table, since they
>   are enclosed inside single quotes.

Because your string is quoted with double quotes (`"INSERT INTO email_list (name, email)  VALUES ('$name', '$email')";`), the entire string has variable expansion performed. If you reversed your use of quotes, then you would get the output you're referring to with `$name` and `$email` in the string.

> Similarly, `echo 'i am going <br />';`  Why its not printing: `i am
>   going <br />`

Well it reality it does, but `<br />` is just a line break and produces no visible output, just a line break. To output a tag like `<br />` and see it, you'd need to output the entity instead, for example `&lt;br /&gt;` which renders as `<br />` in a browser.

For further reading, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score 2):

double quotes forces PHP to evaluate the string (even though it might not be needed), whereas string between single quotes is not evaluated. 
Here is the full description:

[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

ok, because the single quotes are within the double quotes, they are acting as simply single quote characters. They're not acting as delimiters.
ie:

```
"hey guys, I'm going to the movies!" // <-- acting as simple text
"hey guys".' '."eat my food, ok?" // <-- acting as delimiters since it's broken up into three actual strings concatenated by the dot operator.
```

does that make sense?

Comment: you're last string 'i am going <br />' should print the html tag. If it's not, you're probably viewing it through a browser. Check the source for your output.

Comment: so what you meant is single quotes are getting escaped inside the double quotes.....am i right

Comment: Thanks crush, I'm actually not new to stackoverflow, however the account is. My last account was hooked to my last job - so, it kinda went the way of the wind. But thanks nonetheless :)

Comment: @CreationTribe i'm viewing it in browser

Comment: no, not escaped, they're simply within the double quote delimiters, so they're plain text with no function. You could also put double quotes within a single quote string. ' here " are " double " quotes '
If you have something like this: "hey, here's a quote \", nice isn't it?" there, you have to escape it so it doesn't close the string.

Comment: Akash Goel, if you're viewing it in your browser, the html IS being echoed, however you cannot see it since the browser is rendering it.